# jQuery slide initially active

Tags: jquery, flexslider, caption

I have a caption that uses jQuery slide to disappear from view upon clicking an image.

I'm trying to make the caption "slide" toggle initially active (hidden), then have it appear after clicking the image, sliding in from the right (not from the bottom). Thank you for your help!

jQuery:

```
    $("#slideshow").click(function() {
      $( ".flex-caption" ).toggle( "slide" );
    });
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tyuth1sr/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.flex-caption {
    ...
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    display: none;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/tyuth1sr/14/)

Comment: Thanks a lot @isherwood, the display: none did the trick. Unfortunately I have to display the text in the bottom of the caption panel, or I would change the top and padding per your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

one way you could kind of cheese it is by trying to set an absolute height on the caption to !important. That way the jQuery slide function will not be able to change the height making it look like it's coming from the right.

See http://jsfiddle.net/tyuth1sr/11/

I had to change some classes around, and the height will be hard to make responsive imo.
Here is the code I changed:

```
.bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    position:absolute;
}

.flex-caption {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 295px;
    padding-top: 100%;
    bottom: 20px;
    right:0;
    height:650px !important; /* should be set to height of container - 40 for padding */
}

 <div class="flex-caption ">
    <div class="caption-content bottom">
        <p>Taectur sinti consed magnimp oreptatem que est essi cuptus doluptate pratis rero omni con fugitatius venienimus. Xim fuga. Iliqui omnim comnimus estiorrum cum et accus et liquia nos.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

You might be able to give the parent (.flex-slider) a box-sizing:border-box; then give flex-caption a height of 100% !important;